# UnknownAttributeError csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

trying to upload csv record into City model database, getting error

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in PagesController#import

unknown attribute 'country ' for City.  (City.create! row.to_hash)
```

csv:

```
name     country    general_info1    general_info2 (etc)
Toronto  Canada     This is a test   (nil)
```

upload view

```
<%= form_tag upload_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "import" %>
<% end %>
```

route:

```
post '/upload' => 'pages#import'
```

PagesController

```
def import
    City.import(params[:file])
end
```

City model

```
def self.import(file)
    logger.info "__________________"
    logger.info file.inspect
    logger.info file.path
    logger.info "__________________"

    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      City.create! row.to_hash
      #puts '&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&' + row[1]
      logger.info row.inspect
    end
```

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160513090837) do

  create_table "cities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "general_info1"
    t.string   "general_info2"
    t.integer  "happiness_rating"
    t.integer  "family_safety_rating"
    t.string   "family_safety_info"
    t.integer  "bike_hobby_rating"
    t.string   "bike_hobby_info"
    t.integer  "accountant_rating"
    t.integer  "accountant_shortage_rating"
    t.string   "accountant_shortage"
    t.integer  "accountant_avg_salary"
    t.integer  "graphic_designer_rating"
    t.string   "graphic_designer_shortage"
    t.integer  "graphic_designer_avg_salary"
    t.integer  "journalist_rating"
    t.string   "journalist_shortage"
    t.integer  "journalist_avg_salary"
    t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
  end

end
```

many thanks in advance

answer:

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, {headers: true, header_converters: :symbol}) do |row|
        City.create!(row.to_hash)
      end
```

Comment: ... can somebody please explain why the header needs to be a symbol?  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError` occurs if the `field` that `City` models's `create!` method is expecting to be present in `cities` table is absent. Make sure its there.

> can somebody please explain why the header needs to be a symbol?

When you parse CSV in ruby, you normally get the data as collection of `Hash`es. In the following example you might have noticed that the `keys` to all the `Hash`es are repeating and they are `String` data. In `Ruby` every `String` instance occupies separate memory space.

```
csv.to_a.map {|row| row.to_hash }
# => [{"Year"=>"1997", "Make"=>"Ford", "Model"=>"E350", "Description"=>"ac, abs, moon", "Price"=>"3000.00"}, {"Year"=>"1999", "Make"=>"Chevy", "Model"=>"Venture \"Extended Edition\"", "Description"=>"", "Price"=>"4900.00"}, {"Year"=>"1999", "Make"=>"Chevy", "Model"=>"Venture \"Extended Edition, Very Large\"", "Description"=>nil, "Price"=>"5000.00"}, {"Year"=>"1996", "Make"=>"Jeep", "Model"=>"Grand Cherokee", "Description"=>"MUST SELL!\nair, moon roof, loaded", "Price"=>"4799.00"}]
```

Say string `computer` occupies `8 bytes`. if I define this string `1000,000` times, it will occupy `8MB` of my RAM.

Now if you use `header_converters: :symbol`, this will invoke `to_sym` method which will now define the `keys` as `symbol`s.

```
csv = CSV.new(body, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol)
csv.to_a.map {|row| row.to_hash }
# => [{:year=>"1997", :make=>"Ford", :model=>"E350", :description=>"ac, abs, moon", :price=>"3000.00"}, {:year=>"1999", :make=>"Chevy", :model=>"Venture \"Extended Edition\"", :description=>"", :price=>"4900.00"}, {:year=>"1999", :make=>"Chevy", :model=>"Venture \"Extended Edition, Very Large\"", :description=>nil, :price=>"5000.00"}, {:year=>"1996", :make=>"Jeep", :model=>"Grand Cherokee", :description=>"MUST SELL!\nair, moon roof, loaded", :price=>"4799.00"}]
```

**What is special about symbol?**

Symbol is memory efficient and retrieval is very fast. if you define symbol `:computer` `1000,000` times it will only occupy `8Bytes` of memory.

**How is this explanation addressing my question?**

You CSV file might have thousands of lines of data to be converted to `Hash`. So to make this process faster and memory efficient, you use `header_converters: :symbol`

See this for more info http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#HeaderConverters

Comment: ok thank you!   but the fact remains that before i added header_converters: :symbol option, the City instance was bringing back nil for for csv/database conversion, and/or giving me an UnknownAtrributeError, I forget.   when i added the symbol option, it magically worked.

Comment: previous, i tried adding a def init, and an attr_accessor to the model, which also resulted in the same error.   but you can see from the schema, i've got 'country' in there, and i lined up the csv accordingly... row[1] was 'Canada'.   the symbol option must somehow line up the csv with the appropriate model whatever, attribute, but how and why I do not know.

Comment: i also tried # City.create!({
      #   name => row[0],
      #   country => row[1],
      #   general_info1 => row[2],
      #   })
when i added the definit attr_accessors to no avail

Comment: This doesn't work for me because my CSV headers are Camel Case and must be converted to snake_case. `header_converters: :symbol` converts without `_` underscores which will not match my column names. 

What is the ACTUAL issue causing the `UnknownAttributeError` error?